# Fill SKShapeNode with pattern image

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm trying to fill a SKShapeNode with an Image/pattern but I'm still unsuccessfull.

Can you help me solving this or giving me an alternative? **I want to create a collidable custom shape (from any SpriteKit kind) filled with a pattern image.**

I've tried the following:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) radius:50.0 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:(M_PI*2.0) clockwise:YES];
SKShapeNode *shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
UIImage *patternImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern"];
shape.path = path.CGPath;
shape.fillColor = [[SKColor alloc] initWithCGColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:patternImg].CGColor];
```

and also:

```
shape.fillColor = [[SKColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Basketball"].CGImage]];
```

**This works** (but it isn't what I'm looking for):

```
shape.fillColor =  [SKColor redColor];
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think SKShapeNode supports anything but a solid color. Btw, UIColor is the same as SKColor.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks to you I've seen that Cocos2d solves most of the things I'm trying to do, like level design, physics/collisions. I'll take a further look at it today (and to cocos2d-x too). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the sample problem in my game, finally my solution was to add a SKSpriteNode as a child of the SKShapeNode and it worked fine.

```
SKSpriteNode* node = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"bombIcon.png"];
node.name = @"bomb";
node.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
[self.bombNode addChild:node];
```

Where self.bombNode is a SKShapeNode.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Starting from iOS 8.0 there is `fillTexture` property in the SKShapeNode.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to achieve that with `SKCropNode`. However, I've seen several questions here that `SKShapeNode` cannot act as `maskNode` for `SKCropNode`, but I haven't tested it myself. In this case you probably have to use `SKSpriteNode` instead of `SKShapeNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using modern Swift (you're using Swift by now, right?), you could try:

```
var marbleNode: SKSpriteNode!
```

Then later, in your init method:

```
marbleNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SmallerSwirl");

marbleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 35.0)

marbleNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
marbleNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
print(marbleNode.physicsBody)

marbleNode.position = CGPointMake(centerPoint.position.x + 10.0,   centerPoint.position.y + 10.0)

self.addChild(marbleNode)
```

Okay, so that gives us a round sprite node to work with. The Sprite node is responsive to physics, because you set up its physics body separately. So far, so good. Now we need to address the glossed-over part, namely the introduction of the SmallerSwirl .png image.

When you set up your project, it included an Assets.xcassets (pronounced, "x c assets") entry. Click on it, then click on the "+" sign at the middle/bottom of the first column, by the word filter. From the menu that appears, select "New Image Set". A new entry labeled "Image" appears. Click on the word "Image" to change it to "SmallerSwirl".

Next to the SmallerSwirl entry, you see blanks labeled 1x, 2x, and 3x. They are for different screen resolutions. Start by dragging your preferred .png image into the 1x square. That image can be named whatever you want it to be named. It doesn't have to be named SmallerSwirl, though it can be. Drag other images to the 2x and 3x slots if you like.

Run, and you should see your preferred image embodied as a sprite, dancing around the screen.

Comment: Mostly unrelated to the question.