# Load image from iOS 8 framework

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to load an image from an iOS 8 framework that I'm writing (in Swift). I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 6

This code does not work (i.e. load image) if the image is stored in my framework's `Images.xcassets`:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Background.png")
```

If the image is stored in an `Images.xcassets` of a host application (that uses the framework), then the image is loaded properly (from code inside the framework).

I can see that the framework's `Images.xcassets` is included in the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase.

I'm also using a storyboard file as a resource in the framework; and this loads properly.

I've tried renaming the Images.xcassets of the framework to avoid some kind of naming collision with the host application, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

While @Renatus answer is perfectly valid and addresses the core issue (bundle for framework needs to be specified), I wanted to post the solution I went with since it's slightly more direct:

**Swift 3.0/4.0/5.0**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage", in: Bundle(for: YOURFRAMEWORKCLASS.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Alternatively, you can use this pattern for non-`class`, aka non-"static", functions:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

or this pattern for `class` functions:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage", in: Bundle(for: self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

These alternatives are better for cutting and pasting.

Comment: Worked for me, but would be good to elaborate what is meant by YOURFRAMEWORKCLASS. I originally tried the umbrella header but that didn't work, so I replaced it with the main entry point class to the framework... That worked.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your answer, its saved my life, because I was stuck in this issue with 3days, and your answered work perfectly with me...!

Answer (score 13):

UIImage(named: "Background.png") calls NSBundle.mainBundle() in the internals. So, your code is trying to find resource in your host app's bundle, not in the frameworks bundle. To load UIImage from your framework's bundle use this snippet:

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: YOURFRAMEWORKCLASS.self)
let imagePath = frameworkBundle.pathForResource("yourImage.png", ofType: "")
if imagePath != nil {
  result = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath!)
}
```

Edited: added explanation (thx to milz)

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Comment: You should probably not use the image's name with the extension here `yourImage.png` - you want UIKit to choose between @2, @3 etc.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.0:

```
let currentBundle = Bundle(for: YOURCLASS.self)
guard let path = currentBundle.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "jpg") else {  return defaultImage }
return UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) ?? defaultImage
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is assigning the bundle identifier, which makes more sense than assigning class when it comes to readability.

In **Swift 3**:

```
UIImage(named: "MyImage", in: Bundle(identifier: "bundleIdentifier"), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Here's a fool proof way for loading an image embedded in a dynamic framework:

```
    var bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)

    if let bundlePath = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder).resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString("/MYLIB.bundle"), resourceBundle = NSBundle(path: bundlePath) {
        bundle = resourceBundle
    }

    let image = UIImage(named: "my-embedded-image", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```