# NSURL to NSData nil value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurl

I'm trying to convert `NSURL` to `NSData`. My url string is a local file url which I'm getting from my device.

```
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

I'm getting `NSURL` value properly. But while converting it to `NSData` it gives `nil` value. I know there are similar questions in stackoverflow but none of them solves my problem. I'm using swift 2.2

Comment: Is `imageData` nil? try with `contentsOfFile:` instead if it's local, or change the NSURL construction with `fileURLWithPath:`

Comment: If you are loading local file, why do you need to convert it url, nsdata ? Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739762/load-image-from-ios-8-framework

Answer (score 1):

If the string points to a *local file url* then you are using the wrong API. The correct one is

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
```

`NSURL(string:` is only for URL strings which start with a valid file scheme (e.g. `http` or `ftp`)

Comment: Still getting nil value while converting it to NSData. Here is my url string: **"/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1827.JPG"**
Here is what I get after converting it to NSURL:
**file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1827.JPG**

Comment: Do you have access privileges for that directory?

Comment: I dont think so. How do I ensure that??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
let urlString = "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1827.JPG"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
```

Comment: **imageData** is nil

Comment: Maybe it's because of your urlString are you sure that it's correct?

Comment: urlString is a String, you would not know if it is a correct string since String types can't check for the data, you have to go thought each folder and check each and every letter, and remember it's case sensitive.

Comment: Or you can copy the link by right clicking of the file and selecting get info, and coping the link from General dropdown Where:

Answer (score -1):

The Correct one is use **contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL** instead of **contentsOf: forecastURL**

```
  let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "http://photos.state.gov/libraries/media/788/images/90x90.gif")

  let testImage = NSData (contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL)

    print("data",testImage!)

    let image = UIImage(data: testImage! as Data)
    print("imaGE :-",image!)
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation as too why this code helps and what you changed.

Comment: @milo526 
I am adding the **contentsOf: forecastURL! as URL** instead the **contentsOf: url**