# Swift load images from local XML

Tags: ios, swift, xml

In my project I have the following directory structure for Cards:

[image]

And in project I create a simple XML file, from where I could control cards that should be loaded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <root>
    <flashcards>
       <flashcard>
         <images>
           <image>testcard/testimage1</image>
           <image>testcard/testimage2</image>
         </images>
       </flashcard>
    </flashcards>
</root>
```

The following part of code that should convert image path to `UIImage` object

```
 for xmlFlashcardImage in xmlFlashcard["images"]["image"].all {
                        if let imageName = xmlFlashcardImage.element?.text {
                            if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
                                flashCard.images.append(image)
                            } else {
                                #if DEBUG
                                    NSLog("Coudn't load image with path: \(imageName).")
                                #endif
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I tried to play with `FileManager`, but failed too :(

Comment: "I create a simple XML file"  Where is it located and how are you reading it?

Comment: @ElTomato it located in project directory too.

Comment: @ElTomato And I reading it with: https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash

Comment: let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageName.fileURL);
let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)!

Comment: I don't know about your image paths, though.

Comment: @ElTomato I update image of project structure

Comment: @ElTomato I just want to populate my class FlashCard when program starts from XML file. I don't want to do this in code like: let flashCards = [Flashcard(), Flashcard()]

Answer (score 0):

You use UIImage(named: imageName) to get the image from your project Assets (Assets.xcassets). Have a look at some of the answers here: [Load image from iOS 8 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739762/load-image-from-ios-8-framework)

Comment: The problem that I don't want use default assets folder. I created my own folder and I can't figure out what path do I need to set... I want to set path, not names

Comment: I want to set path like UIImage("flashcards/testcard/testcard1.png")

Comment: If you copy the files into your bundle (so they end up in Resources) you can read them using NSBundle. Please read some of the answers, not only the top one.