# Cannot get images from separate pod iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Created a separate pod and as a stand alone project it's working fine. But when I use it in a separate project as a pod the images not showing. Debug the project and image was nil.

```
let image = UIImage.init(named: "arrow_down33x17.png")
```

This is the pod directory structure.
[image]

Comment: Different bundle maybe? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903720/5464805

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828253/7316675

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load resource in cocoapods resource\_bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692265/how-to-load-resource-in-cocoapods-resource-bundle)